# How not to "break up" executing of a method while running

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class which is supposed to be a thread, with overridden run method and a function, which other threads can call by this thread to change some states.

```
public abstract class Node extends Thread
    private final Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<Node>();
    //...other members

    //....constructor to set the nodes

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            node.msg(this);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void msg(Node node) {
        //changing states
        //reading states of node object
        System.out.println(this.toString() + " 1");
        //changing states
        System.out.println(this.toString() + " 2");
    }
}
```

When multiple threads are running I can see such outputs:

```
a 1
b 1
a 2
b 2
```

But I want first msg functions executes till the end and then other threads should be able to send the messages. Because when the thread starts to send messages to the others, but it's states have changed only partly. How can I do that? So I need to have outputs like

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit more with more concrete code examples? It's very hard to understand what problem you're facing and what solution you're asking for.

Comment: @Rubydesic I added some code. The problem is, I'm passing ```this``` to the function msg. And inside the function the states of the node in the parameter will be also read. For example thread A is running and sending some messages to the other nodes. At the same time thread B is also sending a message to A. And then some states of A are changing, but at this time A is sending a message to C and C should read actual states of A, but not all of the states of A have changed, because A is "in the process" of changing its states

Comment: Perhaps you need the [concurrency utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/) to ensure that a thread waits until the other thread finishes?

Comment: @Abra I need to do it without concurrency library, but maybe to do something like that

Comment: If you need 1 thread to do its stuff, then second thread to start, then third, you are looking for a singlethreaded serial execution.

Comment: Create a `static` lock then and lock this section with it.